# Broadcom wifi issue on 14.04 Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, broadcom

I have a brand new 14.04 LTS Lubuntu install on a Dell Inspiron 8600 which is getting wired internet connection, but not wifi. I've attempted some of the previous resolves for this, but seem now to have created a larger problem. At boot up, I get a system error message the detail of which reads

```
KernelOops, kernelBUG at include/net/cfg80211.h:3150!
```

I had previously tried to follow the [instructions to deal with the legacy wifi issue](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).

Specifically the section dealing with Installing b43/b43 legacy firmware, but ran up against error messages trying to with the `sudo apt-get update` command, which ended in the error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run "sudo dpkg --configure -a"
```

When I do this, it appears to run a process relating to the Broadcom card, and appears to complete, but ends in `Segmentation Fault`.

Earlier in the process, I also had experience of the apt command meeting what appears to be an open lock issue, hence I explored [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](/q/15433/), though I cannot tell if I resolved this issue, given the repeated Segmentation fault in response to the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command.

With regard to the Broadcom driver, Software and Updates seemed to have installed the Broadcom STA driver and had it in use according to the additional driver info, but wifi was not working, nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at the additional drivers page,
if you search additional drivers in unity. (Sorry, did not notice you were using Lubuntu, just search for additional drivers.)
There you will come across the different drivers that may be used, which came in handy for me because Ubuntu did not use any driver for my wifi at all.
For me it was just a simple flip from no driver to the broadcom driver.

Hope this will help.