# Lubuntu wireless not works at Acer Aspire 1410

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, aspire

I have an old notebook Acer Aspire 1410.

Previously, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, wireless works perfectly. Currently, I installed Lubuntu 14.04 LTS but the wireless does not work.

ping www.google.com 
ping: unknown host www.google.com

BTW: When I try Lubuntu without installation, I can connect the wireless successfully.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Do you see the Network Manager icon at the top right?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your notebook directly(ethernet), and use that connection to update your drivers, following the instructions in the linked forum page:
[Broadcom wifi issue on 14.04 Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453587/broadcom-wifi-issue-on-14-04-lubuntu)

**Amended**:
in response to a comment by @chili555, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) link documents possible alternatives.
Excerpt from source:

> Ndiswrapper is a Linux module which allows Ubuntu to use the Windows driver for wireless cards. One may want to use ndiswrapper for a number of reasons:

1) No open source driver provided in the Ubuntu repositories.
2) The driver provided by default in Ubuntu is not working out.
3) The proprietary driver provided by the card vendor is not working out.
4) Test ndiswrapper performance versus alternative driver(s).
5) Test hardware failure for your card.

The instructions listed through the link are clear and concise, and should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Why do you think his laptop has a Broadcom card??

Comment: I don't, the intention posting the link is to give reference more generically to updating WiFi drivers, irrespective of card-type, hence my statement "use that connection to update your drivers".

Comment: The Additional Drivers tool only updates drivers for Broadcom cards and not correctly in many cases.

Comment: Avoid ndiswrapper if you can, it's considered 'deprecated' in the modern era.